# iPhoto: How to make an "Abroad" smart album

Tags: macos, photos.app

I want to make a smart album that includes all photos with location information but excludes my home country. But filtering out a certain country just includes all photos without location information. How do I filter out those?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved this. Add a "match all" filter with:

- 'Place' 'contains' "" (blank)
- 'Place' 'is not' "Insert home country"